# Filling an array with objects from a .txt file?

Tags: java, arrays, text

I'm new to Java and am trying to create an array with objects read from a .txt file.
The file looks something like this

```
Wall 2 2
Wall 3 4
Wall 3 5
```

.... and so on.

What I want to do is use the RandomAccessFile() function to fill an array[8][8] with the objects in the file, and in their appointed positions.
I've been looking around but can't find a solution, or maybe I'm not looking in the right place.
Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:

I've made some progress (I think) and am able to read from the .txt file, however, I can't seem to assign objects to specific locations in my array... 
This is what I've got

```
        public static void leer() throws IOException
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("init.txt"));
        while (s.hasNext()) 
        {

            if (s.next()=="Wall")
            {
            int i = s.nextInt();
            int j = s.nextInt();
            Tablero[i][j]=new Wall();

            }
            else if (s.next()=="Ghost")
            {
            int i = s.nextInt();
            int j = s.nextInt();
            Tablero[i][j]=new Ghost();
            }
        }
}
```

Now, I'm getting a "NoSuchElementException", which I gather means I'm not defining the Walls or Ghosts properly, and sadly, I don't quite understand the enum function...
Again, any help would be great!

Comment: Is there anything in particular that separates the objects from one another in the file? A character, something?

Comment: Good time to read up on the Scanner class. Pay attention to the `next` and `nextInt` methods. Here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html.

Comment: Do you mean to say the 2nd column is the object and the 3rd column is its position and you want these two in an array?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII The objects are only separated by a line break in the text file. I practically copied and pasted the 3 example objects (which someone was nice enough to format properly).

Comment: @noMAD The first column (Wall) is the object, with the other two columns being its position in the array [aka (i,j) or (x,y)]

Comment: Well, what you could is you could have a `String` array `String[][] stuff = new String[size][size]` and you could fill it up. But if using array is not a must then I would suggest you use `HashMap<String,String>` because this would be much easier to play with. Also, you might want to store the positions in `String` and convert them using `Integer.parseInt()` when needed.

Comment: @noMAD That's not a bad idea, however I need to stick to certain rules... The point of this program is to make a Pac-Man-like game, filling the game board with walls and ghosts initialized from the text file. Since I'm just starting to learn Java, I'm having issues with adding the objects to the board...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("map.txt"));
String[][] map = new String[8][8];
while (s.hasNext()) {
    String value = s.next();
    int x = s.nextInt();
    int y = s.nextInt();
    map[x][y] = value;
}
```

You might want to consider using an Enum to store the item in each cell:

```
public enum CellType {
    EMPTY, WALL, POWERUP
}

Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("map.txt"));
CellType[][] map = new CellType[8][8];
while (s.hasNext()) {
    String value = s.next().toUpperCase();
    int x = s.nextInt();
    int y = s.nextInt();
    map[x][y] = CellType.valueOf(value);
}
```

---

#### EDIT:

You're calling `.next()` twice in your code. You need to evaluate it only once, so only one token is consumed:

```
public static void leer() throws IOException {  
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("init.txt"));  
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        //Read these at the top, so we don't read them twice, and consume too many tokens 
        String item = s.next();
        int i = s.nextInt();  
        int j = s.nextInt();

        if(item == "Wall") {  
            Tablero[i][j] = new Wall();
        }  
        else if(item =="Ghost") {  
            Tablero[i][j]=new Ghost();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: I was able to implement your code (albeit with a few changes) and got it to work, but can't set the objects in their positions. I edited the main post with my current method.